# Not able to retrieve session values after cURL once in a while

Tags: php, session, curl

I have a strange problem with a payment gateway (Etisalat) for my custom payment page (This only happens for very few people - ~2%).

It's a small form where the client puts the amount and do the payment.

Once the user submits the form, a payment initialization is being done (using JSON) and a transaction id is retrieved (from the remote API). The transaction id is added to a hidden field and the form is fully submitted.

Once the payment process is done (from remote site), it returns to a  finalization URL where it says the Session variable is not found. I can't find where it is getting lost. The browsers this happen are different (win10,chrome/android,chrome/win,firefox etc.)

I'll put the process below. Not the complete code.

Server  ‪Ubuntu 18, PHP 7.3

//index. php

```
<form> name, email, phone amount etc. 
<input type="hidden" transactionId, uniqueId etc./>
</form>

<script>
 event.preventDefault();  

 $.ajax({ url:"PaymentInitiation.php"
 method:"POST",
 dataType:"JSON",
          success:function(data)
          $TransactionID.val(data.Transaction.TransactionID);
          $Form.attr('action', $SubmitURL).submit(); // to the paymentgateway page

</script>
```

//PaymentInitiation. php

```
ob_start();
session_start();
checkValidation;
$_POST values
PDOConnection -> insert initial data to a new row in MySQL table. 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Accept:text/xml-standard-api'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 2443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonRequest ); /// An json_encode array
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . "/certificates/GTE CyberTrust Root.cer"); /* Location in same folder as this file */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response_curl = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response_curl, true);

$_SESSION['TransactionID'] = $json['Transaction']['TransactionID'];
// and many lot of other values are also stored in sessions
//mail sent to admin for payment initiation notice - phpmailer

$PDOConnection = null;
```

//PaymentFinalization. php

```
curl_exec for Finalization with $_SESSION['TransactionID']
```

But TransactionID is empty

Thank you for looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out to be how SameSite cookies are handled. The issue used to come predominantly in Chrome's latest builds, but I've seen it in other browsers as well (Haven't checked which all).

Can be solved by setting PHP variables,
session.cookie_samesite to "None"
and
session.cookie_secure to true

You can set it in php.ini or .htaccess or inside your PHP file accordingly. I used inside my PHP file as I had another application running in the same server which I didn't want to touch.